# MVC failed to make a json string in view for a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a json variable in the view as follows:

```
 @{
        string jsontemp = '{"Cars": {"Nissan": [{"Model": "Sentra", "doors": 4},{"Model": "Maxima", "doors": 4}],"Ford": [{"Model": "Taurus", "doors": 4},{"Model": "Escort", "doors": 4}]}}';
}
```

I want to assign it to a variable in javascript.

```
<script>
var jsondata = @jsontemp;

var arraydata = JSON.parse(jsondata);

</script>
```

But I get the following error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

I understand that when the view is run, my json variable is from the format: `["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]` convert to `[&quot;Ford&quot;, &quot;BMW&quot;, &quot;Fiat&quot;]`

I want to retrieve the json string from view, and assign it to a variable in the script code, then I parse from that string to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `@Html.Raw()` to output the data in raw form.

Otherwise `@` will escape your output by HtmlEncoding it.

```
<script>
    var jsondata = @Html.Raw(jsontemp);
    var arraydata = JSON.parse(jsondata);

</script>
```