# javascript - how to send json by postmessage

Tags: javascript, json, html, asp.net-mvc-4, postmessage

I have a C# string variable having following serialized Json string:

```
{
  "Video": "1",
  "Voice": "1"
}
```

and I am trying to post it via `postMessage` like this:

```
string jsonVerticalTypeQuantity = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VerticalTypeQuantity);

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    parent.postMessage({ "SelectedComponent": "@jsonVerticalTypeQuantity"}, "*");
});
</script>
```

But when I check this in browser it adds extra characters like `&quot` Why is that? and How can I post JSON string as it is?

Comment: Are you trying to use c# variable in javascript ??

Comment: @shajji yes, its a MVC view

Comment: these &quot means double quote (") to replace this u can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244824/how-to-remove-quot-from-my-json-in-javascript)

Comment: is this helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` directive automatically encodes output string while used against a server-side Razor variable as encoded HTML. You should put [`@Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) helper to return unencoded JSON string:

```
parent.postMessage({ "SelectedComponent": @Html.Raw(jsonVerticalTypeQuantity) }, "*");
```

Or use a variable as alternative:

```
@{
    string jsonVerticalTypeQuantity = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VerticalTypeQuantity);
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonData = @Html.Raw(jsonVerticalTypeQuantity);
    parent.postMessage({ "SelectedComponent": jsonData }, "*");
});
</script>
```

Related issue:

[MVC failed to make a json string in view for a variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070660/mvc-failed-to-make-a-json-string-in-view-for-a-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: The syntax error may occur because it not contained as a string. If it's your issue, try using `"@Html.Raw(jsonVerticalTypeQuantity)"` (with double quotes).